# Ubuntu installer doesn't detect my other OS

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have my bootable ubuntu usb stick and the installer guides me through the steps. I get to the step where I'd like to say ''install alongside windows 7'' but the installer tells me that no operating system is detected on my computer.

windows is installed on an ssd while my fat files are on a hdd

Comment: Did you shutdown, not hibernate, Windows? Did you ran `chkdsk /f` in your windows system and restarted twice?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is seeing the HDD before the SSD. I had this issue a few versions ago and I don't know whether the installer has changed since then, but back then I simply unplugged my other drive so only the drive I wanted to install to showed up.

More easily, just change the drive boot priority in your BIOS.